# C# library for Windows store apps, to display .ppt .xls

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-excel, powerpoint

Im searching for a library that allows the viewing of  powerpoint files(.ppt) and Excel files(.xls)

is there anything of sorts in windows store apps?

Comment: What do you mean by "viewing" Would a library that gives you a bitmap image showing the document be OK? Or do you want the ability for viewers to filter Excel rows for instance?